# updating a database

Tags: php, mysql

when i change the product quantity, and update, the data is sent, but it get lost and the update command actually brings the total column to 0, (actually the update code was working fine, untill i edited the form page to include the total at the bottom, below is the screen shots, and the update code

[image: form]

[image]

form script

```
    <?php require_once("include/session.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/dataconnect.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/functions.php");?>
<?php include("include/basicheader.php");?>
<div class="y-acc-contain">
<div class="page-top">
<table width="100% class="y-acc-pagehead">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h1>
"Your account"<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="column-holder">
<div class="primary">
<div class="action-box rounded">
<div class="titlebar">
<h2>Order Form</h2>
</div>
<div class="listbar">
<div>
<?php
$submit = $_POST['Add'];

//form data
$Sname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Sname'])));
$Pname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pname'])));
$Pidno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pidno'])));
$Psize = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Psize'])));
$Pcolour = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pcolour'])));
$Pquantity = $_POST['Pquantity'];
$Weblink = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Weblink'])));
$Price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Price'])));
$date = date("Y-m-d");


if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 

{
if ($Sname&&$Pname&&$Pidno&&$Weblink&&$Price)
{
if (is_numeric($Price))
{
    $repeatheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}' AND Pidno ='$Pidno' AND Sname='$Sname'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($repeatheck);
if($count!=0)
{
    die ('PRODUCT ALREADY IN BASKET YOU CAN INCREASE OR DECREASE QUANTITY');
}
else
$tprice = $Price * $Pquantity;
$queryreg = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO repplac VALUES ('','$Sname','$Pname','$Pidno','$Psize','$Pcolour','$Pquantity','$Weblink','$Price','$tprice','$date','{$_SESSION['username']}')
")or die(mysql_error());
}
else
echo 'price field requires numbers';
}
else
echo 'please fill in all required * fields ';
}
?>
</div>
<form action='youraccount.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>
    <!--<div>
    <label for='shoppinglist' class='fixedwidth'></label>
    <textarea type='text' name='shoppinglist' id='username' cols='100' rows='15'></textarea>
    </div> -->
    <div>
    <label for='Sname' class='fixedwidth'> * Shop name</label>
    <input type='text' name='Sname' id='Sname'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pname' class='fixedwidth'> * Product name</label>
    <input type='text' name='Pname' id='Pname'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pidno' class='fixedwidth'> * Product id no /ad reference</label>
    <input type='text' name='Pidno' id='Pidno'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Psize' class='fixedwidth'>Product size</label>
    <input type='text' name='Psize' id='Psize'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pcolour' class='fixedwidth'>Product colour</label>
    <input type='text' name='Pcolour' id='Pcolour'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pquantity' class='fixedwidth'>Product quantity</label>
    <select name="Pquantity" id="Pquantity">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option> 
</select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Weblink' class='fixedwidth'> * Web link</label>
    <input type='text' name='Weblink' id='Weblink'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Price' class='fixedwidth'> * Price GBP</label>
    <input type='text' name='Price' id='Price'/>
    </div>
    <div>

    <div class='buttonarea'>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'>
            </p>
            </div>
            </p>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="action-box rounded">
<div class="titlebar">
<h2>Shopping List</h2>
<a href='totalprice.php'>Update</a>
</div>
<div class="listbar">

    <form action='orderpplac.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>SHOP NAME</th>
    <th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
    <th>PRODUCT SIZE</th>
    <th>PRODUCT COLOUR</th>
    <th>PRODUCT QUANTITY</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // Get DB results and loop, outputting table rows with counter
    $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) {
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Sname'])."</td>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Pname'])."</td>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Psize'])."</td>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Pcolour'])."</td>
    <td>
    <input type='text' name='item[$i][Pquantity]' id='Pquantity' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pquantity'])."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='item[$i][Pidno]' id='Pidno' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pidno'])."' />
    </td>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Price'])."</td>
    <td>
    <input type='text' name=tprice value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Tprice'])."' readonly>
    </td>
    <td><a href='deleteproduct.php?del=".htmlspecialchars($row['Pidno'])."'>delete</a></td>
    </tr>";
    }
   $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
   //echo $row['Pquantity'] * $row['Price'];
  {
  $totalprice += $row['Tprice'];
  }
  //echo "$totalprice";

         ?>
         <tr>
                <th>Total Price</th>
                <th><?php echo $totalprice; ?></th>

            </tr>
    <!--Close table and form-->

    </table>
    <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='UPDATE' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit2' value='SUBMIT' />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="action-box rounded">
<div class="titlebar">
<h2> payment & balance</h2>
</div>
<div class="listbar">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php include("include/footer.php");?>
```

and this is the script that updates

```
        <?php
require_once("include/session.php");
require_once("include/dataconnect.php"); 
require_once("include/functions.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
if(array_key_exists('item', $_POST)){

    //Loop through $_POST items, updating the database for each item
    foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item) { 
        $Pquantity = intval($item['Pquantity']);
        $Pidno = ($item['Pidno']); 
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
            UPDATE repplac
                 SET Pquantity = {$Pquantity}
                 WHERE
                       Pidno = '{$Pidno}'
                 AND
                       Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
        ") or die(mysql_error());  

    }
    }
    $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
  {
   $Pidno = ($row['Pidno']);
  $totalprice = $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];
   $queryreg = mysql_query("
  UPDATE repplac
  SET Tprice = {$totalprice}
  WHERE
                       Pidno = '{$Pidno}'
                 AND
                       Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
    ") or die(mysql_error());  
  }

    }
    else if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    //Get Email Address
    $emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")or die(mysql_error());
    //$emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $results = (mysql_fetch_assoc($emails)) or die(mysql_error());
    $email= $results['email'];

   if(mysql_num_rows($emails) == 0){
         exit("No email addresses found for user '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
    }
    $email = mysql_result($emails, 0);

    //Get list to email user
   $body = "<html><body><table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Shop Name</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Color Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>";
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){ 
    $body .= "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['Sname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pname'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Psize'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pcolour'] ."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Pquantity'] ."</td>
        </tr>";
}

$body .="</table></body></html>";

   //Send email
$to = $email; 
   $subject = "YOUR ORDER LIST FROM REACHEASY"; 
$headers = "From: donotreply@rapsody.co.uk\r\n";  
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
        //Transfer records to wishlist 
    $transfer = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wishlist (SELECT  * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}')")or die(mysql_error());
    // Delete temporary records if the above query was successful:
    if($transfer !== false){
        $deletetable = mysql_query("DELETE FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
    }
}
redirect_to('youraccount.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Is that a typo or your update form has two form tags in it?

Comment: Please fix your code then - both indentation and accuracy

Comment: you will need to include `Total` calculation in `UPDATE` command too... as you are not including, `Total` by default is **ZERO**

Comment: could you provide full code??

Comment: please remove unnecessary comments in the code. For example `//echo $row['Pquantity'] * $row['Price'];` if this isn't relevant or it won't help us help you, then please don't include it.

Comment: ok, will remove all comments and post full code

Comment: did you get what I said above regarding `Total`... I have doubt that that is your problem...

Comment: @FahimParkar does that mean i will have to create a column for the total, in the database, so as to update, or i will have to pass it as a post variable to work with it

Comment: in update you don't have anything related to `Total`, hence value is set to ZERO as initial value of Total is 0... hope you got the problem...

Comment: no, i main file you are calculating Total... Right? same way you will need to do in Update file too...

Comment: @FahimParkar i dint get that, could you come again

Comment: you have `$totalprice += $row['Tprice'];` in your main file.. but in update file you don't have `$totalprice += $row['Tprice'];`

Comment: @FahimParkar i have added $totalprice += $row['Tprice'];, and its still same, i kept after the while loop for  $row['Tprice'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quantity is being set to 0 because intval is not able to cast your quantity to a valid number. You need to debug what is coming back in your $item submit.

Comment: when i have post result, it gives this Array ( [item] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Pquantity] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [Pidno] => 123 ) ) [tprice] => 24 [submit2] => SUBMIT ) , which is alright because for this field the quantity i entered was 2

Comment: Your output shows that $item does not have an key of 'Pquantity'. That value is in a subarray. Looks like you'll need $item[0]['Pquantity'] or in your loop $item[$i]['Pquantity']

Comment: thats true, i can see what you re saying

Comment: Great! Would you mind upvoting and selecting this as your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the `$i` on the line

```
"<input type='text' name='item[$i][Pquantity]' id='Pquantity' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pquantity'])."' />"
```

from? Are you throwing all errors so that you can see if PHP is complaining about anything? What is your error level set at?

Also, the last piece of your code could use the `SUM` SQL aggregator function, as in:

```
SELECT SUM(Tprice) FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
```